# How to stop a function?

Tags: r, function

I want to stop the function when it is in certain condition, and not continue to the following function.

```
whole <- function(z)            #z: file name
{
  u=1
  U=matrix(nrow = length(z)-1-(sum(apply(z,2,function(x)length(table(x))==1))),ncol=2)
  for (h in (2:length(z)))
  {
    if (length(table(z[h]))==1) {
      next
    }
    newname = with(z,table(z[,1],z[,h]))
    newname = as.data.frame.matrix(newname)
    if (sum(newname==0) > 0) {
      stop(matrix(c(names(newname)[1],names(newname)[2]),nrow = 1,ncol = 2))
    }
    if (is.ordered(z[,h])==TRUE)
    {     
      repeat
      {
         k=1
```

What's wrong with the line including 'stop'?

Comment: Change `stop` to `return` if you want the function to return that matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stop` is how you raise an error (when you want to). You're looking for `break`. Beware, it has a weird syntax; see `?break`.

Comment: Or `return`, if you want to pass something when you stop execution (h/t RichardScriven).